# Changing View Height on Android when open keyboard

Tags: css

I have an input on the page

[image: Closed keyboard]

But when I click on input and opens keyboard, only on Android the view height size changes and the page is crashing

[image: Opened keyboard]

How to block view height change when keyboard opened on Android devices

Comment: please share code related to that block view

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMqXJG but there is a big angular2+ app, you can't run only this block